# Como criar uma função em Javascript que aceita um número arbitrário de argumentos?

Tags: javascript, funções

Funções do tipo `console.log` recebem um número qualquer de argumentos. Como especificar isso para uma função em Javascript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No Javascript, toda função, independente dos argumentos especificados em sua assinatura, possui um objeto `arguments`. Esse objeto contém todos os argumentos passados para a função. Mas a princípio ele é do tipo `object`, então é comum fazer isso para transformá-lo em um tipo `Array`:

```js
function minhaFuncao() {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) console.log(args[i]);
}

minhaFuncao(1, 2, 3); // args = [1, 2, 3];
```

O código acima chama a função `slice` do protóripo de `Array` em `arguments`, retornando uma `Array` para podermos usar seus objetos mais facilmente.

Em casos quando você quer ter um número de argumentos fixos, e depois argumentos variáveis, basta mudar o número passado como segundo argumento para `slice.call`:

```js
function minhaFuncao(x, y) {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 2);
  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) console.log(args[i]);
}

minhaFuncao(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // x = 1, y = 2, args = [3, 4, 5];
```

Answer (score 5):

Uma abordagem mais aconselhável é passar um mapa de argumentos:

```
function DoSomething(config) {
   config = config || {};
   var idioma = config.Idioma || "en-GB";
}
```

A primeira linha inicializa um mapa vazio, caso a função tenha sido chamada sem argumentos: `DoSomething();`

A função pode ser chamada assim:

```
DoSomething({ idioma : "pt-PT", outraChave: "outro valor" });
```

Esta abordagem tem 2 vantagens:

- Pode-se atribuir nomes aos argumentos, tornando mais fácil manter o código ao longo do tempo;
- Como o processamento depende do *nome* dos argumentos, e não da sua *ordem*, podemos simplesmente omitir valores - em vez de chamar a função com `null`:

  **Por exemplo**

  Digamos que a funcao espera 4 argumentos `(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)`, em vez de:

  ```
  DoSomething(null, null, null, "ola");
  ```

  Utilizaríamos:

  ```
  DoSomething({arg4: "ola"});
  ```

Vários métodos das bibliotecas do jQuery utilizam esta abordagem para passar um conjunto de dados de configuração.

Comment: É uma boa alternativa, mas para um caso diferente. Usar um `object` te permite especificar "opções", ou parâmetros nomeados, enquanto o `arguments` é basicamente açúcar sintático pra passar uma array.

Comment: Concordo. Como a pergunta nao especificava o caso de uso, decidi sugerir esta opcao. Ambos teem o seu uso. `arguments` e' o mais adequado para implementar o exemplo dado na pergunta (`console.log`), em outros casos seria melhor ter um mapa de argumentos.

Answer (score 4):

Um exemplo:

```
function somar() {
    var resultado = 0;

    for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
        resultado += arguments[i];
    }
    return resultado;
}

console.log(somar(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 5, 8, 7)); // = 30

console.log(somar(1, 1, 1)); // = 3
```

---

Ou seja, basta usar a variável especial `arguments` para cada argumento passado para a função. Sendo `arguments[0]` o 1º argumento, `arguments[1]` o 2º argumento e assim por diante.