# Métodos com o mesmo nome mas com quantidade de parâmetros diferentes

Tags: javascript, funções, sobrecarga

Em C# ou Java em uma classe eu posso definir métodos com o mesmo nome mas com as variáveis diferentes, assim:

```
//em C#
public class Classe {
    public String teste(String hello, String world){
        return  hello + world;
    }
    public String teste(String full){
        return full;
    }
    public String teste(){
       return "hello world";
    }
}
```

Preciso saber como eu poderia gerar métodos com esse mesmo sentido onde o nome método é o mesmo mas dependendo dos elementos que eu enviar ele irá processar um bloco de código ou outro...

Comment: Pela resposta aceita ficou claro que a intenção da pergunta é a mesma de pergunta já existente, então votei para fechar como duplicata.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O que é feito em javascript a esse respeito é criar uma função e, no começo da implementação da função, analisar e tratar os argumentos pra que ela possa ser usada de uma forma mais dinâmica. Ao definir uma função duas vezes o javascript sobrescreve a primeira implementação da função, você não tem imutabilidade.

Uma função que traduziria a funcionalidade que você busca, escrita em javascript, seria a seguinte:

```
function teste() {
  if(arguments.length === 0)
    return "hello world"

  if(arguments.length === 1 &&
    typeof(arguments[0]) === 'string')
    return arguments[0];

  if(arguments.length === 2 &&
    typeof(arguments[0]) === 'string' &&
    typeof(arguments[1]) === 'string')
    return arguments[0] + arguments[1];
}

// Para casos tratados
teste(); // "hello world"
teste("teste1"); // "teste1"
teste("teste1", "teste2"); // "teste1teste2"

// Para casos não tratados
// Quando uma função não retorna, explicitamente, nenhum valor, você recebe undefined
teste("teste1", "teste2", "teste3"); // undefined
teste(1); // undefined
teste("teste1", 1); // undefined
```

Dentro do escopo de toda função você pode acessar a variável `arguments`. Essa variável representa um objeto cujos índices são números, iniciando em zero. Acredito que essa seja a chave para resolver seu problema.

Ex.:

```
// arguments = {length: 0}
teste();

// arguments = {length: 1, 0: "teste1"}
teste("teste1");

// arguments = {length: 2, 0: "teste1", 1: "teste2"}
teste("teste1", "teste2");

// arguments = {length: 3, 0: "teste1", 1: "teste2", 2: "teste3"}
teste("teste1", "teste2", "teste3");

// arguments = {length: 1, 0: 1}
teste(1);

teste("teste1", 1); // arguments = {length: 2, 0: "teste1", 1: 1}
```

Comment: cara, eu vejo o JS como uma linguagem muito boa pra quem trabalha na web mas sinto falta do que se tem em linguagens tipadas... mas valeu parceiro, muito boa essa lógica sua

Comment: @LeandroLUK concordo que JS é deficitária e por isso eu me interesso e estudo linguagens funcionais como http://www.erlang.org/, http://elm-lang.org e busco, um dia, aprender https://www.haskell.org/

Answer (score 5):

Isso se chama *sobrecarga de métodos*. Não, isso não é possível da forma que você está querendo fazer em JavaScript.

Entretanto, JavaScript não rejeita a passagem de uma quantidade de parâmetros diferente do que está declarado na assinatura da função. Se você tem uma função

```
function funcaoComAridade2(parametro1, parametro2) {
    console.log("Primeiro: " + parametro1);
    console.log("Segundo: " + parametro2);
}
```

nada te impede de chamá-la assim:

```
funcaoComAridade2(33);
```

O único problema é que `parametro2` receberá o valor `undefined`.

Você pode, inclusive, descobrir a quantidade de parâmetros passados. Basta obter o tamanho (`length`) do objeto estilo-vetor `arguments` dentro da função. Esse objeto contém os parâmetros de fato recebidos, independente de quantos sejam. Você pode basear-se nisso para decidir, no corpo do método, que caminho tomar.

Comment: `arguments` não é um vetor, essa variável é um objeto. Mas o resto da explicação procede, na minha opinião

Comment: Eu o chamei de "objeto estilo-vetor". Não quis explicar a fundo para não prolongar algo que é detalhe.

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade, são parâmetros diferentes, isto é chamado *overloading* (sobrecarga).

Em JavaScript isto não é possível por não ter o recurso mencionado, tem que por alguma coisa no nome para diferenciar um do outro. Tente achar um nome sugestivo que indica a diferença, se não for possível indique a diferença especificando o(s) tipo(s) no nome, mas tente deixar o mais intuitivo possível.

Na verdade isto nem seria possível tecnicamente já que JavaScript não tem tipos estáticos, pelo menos até a versão atual, o que dificulta a decisão.

É possível simular isto com verificações dentro do corpo da função. Ou seja, você teria apenas uma função aceitando diversos parâmetros. Dentro teria alguns `ifs` analisando a quantidade de parâmetros efetivamente passados e eventualmente o tipo de cada um deles. A decisão de que partes da função (ou delegar para outras) devem ser executadas partirá do que for decidido aí. Existem outras técnicas passando objetos ou usando a [técnica de *default arguments*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15350/101).

[Exemplos escritos pelo John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-method-overloading/). Veja [pergunta sobre o tema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93144/101) com mais exemplos.

Em [linguagens dinâmicas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101) diversos mecanismos precisam ser escritos pelo programador.

Mesmo [TypeScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49408/101) ([mais informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/101)) que possui tipos não tem a capacidade de decidir pelos tipos. Se fizesse isto teria complicações para gerar o fonte JS. Ela é capaz de decidir apenas pela quantidade de parâmetros.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu preferi não dar exemplos, porque está cheio de perguntas no SOpt com exemplos, no fundo, respondendo eu percebi até que a pergunta é duplicada.