# Função que passa argumentos dinamicamente para callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como passar argumentos numa função callback (geralmente, função anônima)?

Talvez fique difícil entender, então vou dar um exemplo aqui. Vejo sempre isso em bibliotecas como jQuery, mas não entendo como funciona no JS "puro".

**Por exemplo:**

```
// essa é a função que passa um argumento qualquer para dentro de seu callback
function passarArgumento(callback){

}

// função anônima de callback recebe e printa o argumento nos 2 exemplos abaixo
passarAgumento(function(argumento){
      alert(argumento);
})

passarArgumento(function(valor){
      alert(valor);
})
```

**A minha dúvida é:** como a `passarArgumento()` faz para jogar o valor para dentro do callback, e ainda ter o nome variável, como no exemplo (argumento, valor)?

*Update*

**Outro exemplo é a função ajax do jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
   success: function(resposta){
     // a função $.ajax jogou a resposta do request aqui. Como isso é feito?
     alert(resposta);
  }
});
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como o jQuery faz os parâmetros serem dinâmicos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93144/como-o-jquery-faz-os-par%c3%a2metros-serem-din%c3%a2micos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nome da variável podes mudar como quiseres. Isso é definido quando defines a callback. Para executar essa callback e ativar o `alert` no teu caso, basta invocares a função. Ou seja:

```
function passarArgumento(callback){
    callback('aqui passas o que a callback deve retornar');
}
```

Exemplo:

```js
// essa é a função que passa um argumento qualquer para dentro de seu callback
function passarArgumento(callback, tipo) {
  callback('aqui passas o que a callback deve retornar ' + tipo);
}

// função anônima de callback recebe e printa o argumento nos 2 exemplos abaixo
passarArgumento(function(argumento) {
  alert(argumento);
}, 'A')

passarArgumento(function(valor) {
  alert(valor);
}, 'B')
```

Outra maneira de ver o problema:

Quando passamos uma função como argumento, não sabemos quando será chamada, nem quantos argumentos irá receber. Quem controla isso é o momento e maneira que é invocada.

Exemplo:

```js
function tipoA(callback) {
  callback('vou passar', 'dois argumentos');
}

function tipoB(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback('argumento unico, mas atrasado');

  }, 2000);
}

tipoA(function(a, b) {
  console.log(arguments.length, a, b);
})

tipoB(function(a, b) {
  console.log(arguments.length, a, b);
})
```

Comment: Ainda não era bem isso, Sergio. Eu atualizei a pergunta. Vê se você consegue compreender agora, por favor. Valeu!

Comment: @inovapixel a ideia é a mesma, juntei mais uma explicação  e exemplo. Dá uma olhada.

Comment: Já consegui resolver. Obrigado pela ajuda.