# O que seria parâmetros dinâmicos javascript?

Tags: javascript

O que seria parametros dinamicos no javascript?

Comment: vale a pena ler, não é exatamente  o que você perguntou "mas e como se fosse" http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93144/como-o-jquery-faz-os-par%C3%A2metros-serem-dinamicos

Comment: Explique um pouco melhor a que você se refere por parametros dinâmicos.

Comment: [Como criar uma função em Javascript que aceita um número arbitrário de argumentos?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4293/91) seria isso?

Comment: Guilherme, sua pergunta está com 4 votos para ser colocada em suspenso (pode ser reaberta), mas ao mesmo tempo tem 3 votos positivos e uma resposta bem legal; provavelmente ficará aberta e será popular. Mas para benefício de outros que tenham a mesma dúvida que você e encontrem a solução aqui, será que pode descrever melhor o porquê da sua pergunta? É que quando o título e descrição são exatamente iguais fica bem estranho...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parâmetros dinâmicos ocorrem quando sua função aceita um número variável de argumentos, tipo:

```
minhaFuncao(x)
minhaFuncao(x, y, z)
```

A quantidade de argumentos pode ser finita, tipo 1 ou 2 ou 3 argumentos aceitos, mas podem também ser indeterminada, em aberto. Veja dois exemplos:

```
function recado(mensagem, nome){
    if(typeof nome == 'undefined'){
        nome = 'Amigo';
    }
    alert('Recado para ' + nome + ': ' + mensagem);
}
recado('Tenha um bom dia.'); //resultado: 'Recado para Amigo: Tenha um bom dia.'
recado('OK', 'Guilherme'); //resultado: 'Recado para Guilherme: OK'

function soma(inicio){
    var resposta = inicio;
    if(arguments.length > 1) {
        for(var i=1; i<arguments.length; i++){
            resposta += arguments[i];
        }
    }
    return resposta;
}
soma(3); // retorna 3
soma(100, 10, 2, 3); // retorna 115
```

Comment: Exatamente isso, Obrigado pelo seu tempo!