# Como retornar a quantidade de argumentos e somar os valores dos argumentos em uma função javascript

Tags: javascript

Preciso saber como retornar a quantidade de argumentos.

Exemplos:
lista(vermelho, verde, azul)
Retorna 3

lista(1,45,33,50)
Retorna 4

Sendo que não é possível saber a quantidade préviamente

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como criar uma função em Javascript que aceita um número arbitrário de argumentos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4293/como-criar-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-javascript-que-aceita-um-n%c3%bamero-arbitr%c3%a1rio-de-argumento)

Comment: Apesar da pergunta sugerida como duplicada não ter o mesmo título, na primeira resposta explica como usar o `arguments`, que é o que vc precisa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode utilizar o [objeto de argumentos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es#Using_the_arguments_object) e pegar o seu length, obtendo assim a quantidade de argumentos passados na função, no exemplo foi utilizado um [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) para que a função possa receber um número indefinido de argumentos:

```js
function lista(...args) {
  return arguments.length
}

console.log(lista(1,2,3))
console.log(lista(1,2,3,4,5))
console.log(lista(1,2))
```

Para pegar a soma por exemplo dos argumentos, pode fazer desta maneira:

```js
function lista(...args) {
  let result = 0;

  for (const soma of args) {
    result += soma;
  }
  return result;
}

document.write('A soma total é: ', lista(1,2,3))
```

Comment: Obrigado resolveu!

Comment: De nada. Se alguma das repostas lhe serviu de alguma maneira, poderia aceitar alguma para que sua questão fique como resolvida no site?

Comment: Se não for abusar. Caso eu quizesse somar os valores passados no ...args como faria?

Comment: Não entendi bem, somar os números passados pra função, lista(1,2,3), estes números?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Somar os numeros nos argumentos passados em ...args

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Valeu. Editei a pergunta para abranger a resposta.

Answer (score 3):

O objeto [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) corresponde aos argumentos passados para uma função. 
É parecido com objeto Array correspondendo mas não é um `Array`.

Aqui é usada a propriedade `arguments.length` para retornar o número de argumentos a função

```js
function verbosa() {
   return arguments.length;
}

console.log(verbosa(1, "batatinha", 2));
```

`arguments` pode ser iterado tal qual um array.

```js
function verbosa2() {
   for(i=0, str = "" ; i < arguments.length; i++ ){
      str = str + arguments[i] + "\n";
   }   
   return "" + str;
}

console.log(verbosa2(1, "batatinha", 2));
```

Mas não é um `array` pois não possui seus métodos.

```js
function verbosa3a() {
   try {   
      return arguments.join(",");
   } catch (e){
      return "Deu erro na verbosa: " + e;
   } 
}

console.log(verbosa3a(1, "batatinha", 2));
```

Se quiser usar os argumento tal qual um `array` deve se [converter para array](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from),

```js
function verbosa3b() {   
   return Array.from(arguments).join(",");
}

console.log(verbosa3b(1, "batatinha", 2));
```

Se quiser utilizar os argumentos diretamente como um `Array` sem fazer a conversão deve [parâmetros rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

```js
function verbosa4(...args) {         
      return args.join(",");       
}

console.log(verbosa4(1, "batatinha", 2));
```

Comment: Obrigado. Sua resposta foi muito boa. Me ajudou muito

Answer (score 1):

Basta utilizar a propriedade `length` da função. Veja o exemplo a seguir:

```
function f1(a) {
  console.log("aqui tem 1")
}

function f2(a, b) {
  console.log("aqui vai ter 2")
}

function f3(a, b, c, d) {
  console.log("nessa vai ter 4")
}

console.log(f1.length)

console.log(f2.length)

console.log(f3.length)
```

[Clique aqui para ver a referência.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Length)

Comment: Mas o `length` retorna a quantidade parâmetros esperada (ou seja, o que foi declarado na criação da função). Mas se vc chamar a função com uma quantidade diferente de argumentos (ex: `f1(1,2,3)`), o `length` não dirá quantos têm (que é o que a pergunta pede).

Comment: Não funciona para o caso da pergunta o usuário especificou **"..que não é possível saber a quantidade previamente..."**.

Comment: Obrigado por responder